# SIP Trunk messaging

Tags: sip, voip, trunk

I need to make an application which appears to an enterprise PBX as a SIP trunk.

I've not been able to find a good description of the actual messaging involved in a call made through a SIP trunk.

I did a capture of a call through a PBX --> trunk --> PBX in house, and it looked to me to be identical to a "302 Moved Temporarily" call flow. However, I was told that this was not correct either.

What I'm looking for is an example of the message flow, or at least a description of it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no headers to indicate SIP Trunk in the SIP message per se. The Trunks are usually identified when they either REGISTER on behalf of a few numbers the PBX can serve.

The Specs can be found here - https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6140

But this one of the newest form of Bulk registration. Other than that there are specs in SIPConnect to determine the Trunk - PBX interaction. I am not entirely what the PBX is expecting from.

I am not sure what you mean by the "302 " Call Flow.